# Adding cookie to BasicHttpBinding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, cookies, basichttpbinding

Hello i have a web service on server. I am connecting to this web service with client based on  BasicHttpBinding. We add to this service cookie based authentication and now i want to add support for cookies to my client.

So this is my MyServiceClient class:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class MyServiceClient: System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IMyServiceClient>, IMyServiceClient
{
    ... ctors ....

   [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    CheckAuthorizationResponse IMyServiceClient.CheckAuthorization(CheckAuthorizationRequest request)
    {
        return base.Channel.CheckAuthorization(request);
    }

    ... ...
}
```

This is how i create client:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding("MyServiceSoapBinding");
binding.AllowCookies = true;       // trying to experiment with this
var client = new MyServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(endpointAddr),installation.CertThumbprint);
return client;
```

and this is my CheckAuthorization implementation:

```
public bool CheckAuthorization()
{
    CheckAuthorizationRequest inValue = new CheckAuthorizationRequest();
    CheckAuthorizationResponse retVal = ((IMyServiceClient)(this)).CheckAuthorization(inValue);
    return retVal.checkAuthorizationResult;
}
```

and i know value of the cookie so lets say:
    string cookiecontent = "blabla";

and now i need to add this cookie to my client and whenever i call the CheckAuthorization the cookie will pass. Any ideas how to do it? I am ending with exception "The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Basic'."

Comment: I anybody hit this question like me, there is a good blogpost on the subject at http://megakemp.com/2009/02/06/managing-shared-cookies-in-wcf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved this by adding:

```
using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    var endPoint = new EndpointAddress(url);
    var authCookie = new System.Net.Cookie("Auth", cookie);
    var cookies = new CookieContainer();
    cookies.Add(new Uri(url), authCookie);
    var httpRequest = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add(System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequest);
    httpRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookies.GetCookieHeader(endPoint.Uri));

    var authChecked = client.CheckAuthorization(request);
}
```

and also i must add:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding("MyServiceSoapBinding");
binding.AllowCookies = false;
```